# Is ubuntu available and working on my Huawei smartphone?

Tags: system-installation

Can I install ubuntu on my Huawei gra L09 - smartphone?
My smartphone has Emui version is 4.0.1.; operating system Android 6.

Comment: Supported versions can be found here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices And you need specific firmware for anything else. Wrong place to ask. Have a look at the XDA forums. http://www.xda-developers.com/

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't unless you're a programmer. Start here: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/porting-new-device/

The state of the support for a few devices can be checked here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices